# Conditional statement in a for loop simple as i

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

I found these lines of code in a library made to listen to touch events :

```
  for ( var i = elements.length; i; i-- ) {
    iterator( elements[ i - 1 ], elements );
  }
```

It surprised me for a second. I understand the code this way : i is an integer positive or null and the conditional statement is if i positive.
Do I understand right ? Does i return false when i==-1 ? Or did i miss something (like it's possible to write a for loop without a conditional statement) ?

Comment: This is just a reverse `for` loop, and it's very common with live nodeLists to avoid issues when modifying the nodeList. Otherwise you seem  to get it, and it should be trivial to log `i` in the loop and see when it stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional is essentially `if( i) proceedToNextIteration();`

As numbers go, only zero is falsy and would fail the check. `-1` would be true in the above condition.

For this reason, I'd rewrite that code as:

```
for( var i = elements.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    iterator( elements[i], elements);
}
```

It's much more explicit about its final condition.

Comment: Yeah, but it is like **5 more characters** when including white space. That's like **a lot**!!

Comment: In my opinion, that's completely uneccessary and not easier to read, when iterating a nodeList and using `i--` it's impossible to end up anywhere other than on zero. I would write it `for ( var i=elements.length; i--; ) {...`

Comment: Very explicit, I now understand the way this code works. Is the code I posted able to be used with any for loop or does it only work with a nodeList ?

Comment: Nice answer, it helped me ! You get the accepted answer tick !

Answer (score 2):

This is the structure of the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) in Javascript:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

The statement you provided 
    for ( var i = elements.length; i; i-- )

adheres to this syntax. This is same as

```
for(var i = 10; i!=0; i--)
```

Meaning loop from `10` (`elements.length`) to `1`. Similar to looping from `1` to `10`.

In Javascript, the condition `i != 0` can be replaced with just `i`.

Meaning:

```
if(i != 0)
```

and

```
if (i)
```

are the same. That is what is done in the condition part.

Looping over elements of a list or array from max to 0 is helpful when removing items from it.

Comment: To be accurate, the condition is `i != 0`, not `i>0`.

Comment: Nice answer. Furthermore, can we get true or false from an integer without using an if statement (like : if(i){j=true}else{j=false}) ?

Comment: @EtienneWan you can. `j = !!i`. But using an explicit conditional makes it more readable: `if` like you posted, or a conditional opertor: `j = i? true : false`.